# NPM error when building a Ruby on Rails 7.1.0.beta1 Dockerfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, dockerfile, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm using Ruby on Rails 7.1.0.beta1 to develop a very simple web app to deploy to fly.io. Rails 7.1 automatically creates a Dockerfile. But when I try "docker build -t demo ." I keep getting an error pointing to the 3rd line below (the 'npm' line):

```
# Install JavaScript dependencies
ARG YARN_VERSION=1.22.19
    npm install -g yarn@$YARN_VERSION && \
    rm -rf /tmp/node-build-master
```

The exact error is:

```
$ ~/dev/myapp$ docker build -t demo .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  172.5kB
Error response from daemon: dockerfile parse error line (31): unknown instruction: NPM
$ npm -v
9.5.1
$ docker -v
Docker version 20.10.24, build 297e128
```

The above is while working on Windows 10 Pro using WSL and Ubuntu. But, I get nearly the same error message doing the same on my MacOS system at home. Maybe Rails 7.1.0.beta1 is too early for me?

Any thoughts?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean to have the keyword `RUN` at the start of that `npm` line?  (Also consider running this particular step in a separate build stage `FROM node`.)

Comment: To clarify, I did not create the Dockerfile. I was created by Rails automatically in 7.1.0.beta1. So once I figure this out, I will probably let the Rails development team know of my experience. But thank you for the point about adding RUN. I will try it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is Dockerfile template

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/Dockerfile.tt

I don't know why, but in your file [these lines](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/Dockerfile.tt#L28-L30) are absent (between `ARG YARN_VERSION=1.22.19` and `npm install -g yarn@$YARN_VERSION && \`):

```
ENV PATH=/usr/local/node/bin:$PATH
RUN curl -sL https://github.com/nodenv/node-build/archive/master.tar.gz | tar xz -C /tmp/ && \
    /tmp/node-build-master/bin/node-build "${NODE_VERSION}" /usr/local/node && \
```

Your attempt to check `npm -v` is not helpful, because it is your local npm version. Inside container can be another version